# Software to build a site like FreeLancer.com

Tags: linux, web-apps, cms, self-hosted

For my nonprofit I want to build a site similar to FreeLancer.com, that is some users post jobs and some users work for others.

Is there (desirably free) ready software to do this?

My site should not only earn money for the nonprofit but also fulfill the mission of advertising high integrity programming.

I want to run it on a Debian Linux server.

---

In response to @Izzy comment:

The main requirement for the program I want is: *connect people which need some work to be done to freelancers in a way efficient for a business* (so that the freelancers get paid, purchasers have their work done, and my organization which provides this service has a profit).

I do not know which particular features this "efficient for a business" feature depends on. I want it to just work. I am not an outsourcing expert. I want the software which I acquire be profitable.

These features include also:

- responsive design.

I need also a special feature: I want the possibility to display a big noticeable link to FAQ, where I am going to describe how my site is different than most other FreeLancer.com clones. This way I need some infrastructure allowing easily enough to change the design.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Consider not everyone knowing FreeLancer.com: what features do you need?